# Need an upper bound for a simple expectation involving Rademacher random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, rademacher-distribution

I need an upper bound on the following expectation:
$$E_{x_1,\dots,x_n} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \right| \quad,\quad \mbox{s.t.} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=1.$$

Here $x_i$'s are iid Rademacher random variables ($x_i=+1$ or $x_i=-1$, each with probability $1/2$) and |.| is the absolute value. The real vector $(a_1,...a_n)$, as shown, is on the unit sphere.

What is the best upper bound you know for this expectation? Getting a bound using Holder's inequality is straightforward,
\begin{equation}
E_{x_1,\dots,x_n} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \right| \leq E_{x_1,\dots,x_n} \|\boldsymbol{a}\|_1 \|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{\infty} = \|\boldsymbol{a}\|_1
\end{equation}
However, I am hoping for a tighter bound.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using $E\big[X\big]^2 \leq E\big[X^2\big]$ (Jensen) allows you to (i) linearize the absolute value and (ii) use explicitly use  $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=1$.

$\Big(E_{\mathbf x} \big[ \vert\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i \vert\big]\Big)^2$
$\leq E_{\mathbf x} \big[ (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i \big)^2\big]$
$=E_{\mathbf x} \big[ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 X_i^2  \big] + E_{\mathbf x} \big[ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i} a_ia_j X_iX_j  \big]$
$= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 E_{\mathbf x} \big[X_i^2  \big] +  \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i} a_ia_j E_{\mathbf x} \big[X_i\big]E_{\mathbf x} \big[X_j  \big]$
$= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 +0$
$=1$

taking square roots
$E_{\mathbf x} \big[ \vert\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i \vert\big]\leq 1$

recall
$\big\Vert \mathbf a\big\Vert_2 \leq \big\Vert \mathbf a\big\Vert_1$
by triangle inequality so this is a sharper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Is there any way to get a sharper bound that is not a constant, and still depends on a_1,...a_n)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such bound... and it has 2 things going against it.  (1.) it seems  unnatural to throw out the information that $\big\Vert \mathbf a\big \Vert_2 = 1$. (2.) The standard technique in probability for dealing with absolute values of sums of random variables (e.g. Kolmogorov Inequality) is to upper bound them using second moments.